# Store Time value string hh:mm AM/PM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, sql-server-2012

I am trying to save a time string in the database in the form of HH:MM AM/PM format. e.g. 12:00 AM to 11:00 PM. These strings are already defined in the code. What is the best data type to store these strings in database using SQL Server 2012.

What is the better way? a generic list in the code to populate values when page loads and then store or store all values in the database from 12:00 AM to 11:00 PM and then get from database.

Comment: Why not use a datetime in the database then convert it to string in the code?

Comment: What is the better way? a generic list in the code to populate values when page loads or store all values in the database from 12:00 AM to 11:00 PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use DateTime or DateTime2 in the database it's a 24 hour clock, there is no AM/PM format. You get an AM/PM format by doing this in the code:

```
dateTime.ToString("tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```